# How to use ajax GET or POST method to pass data to Amazon lambda node.js function

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the node.js code below (following [Getting Started with REST APIs in Amazon API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)):

```
console.log('Loading event');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
var name = (event.name === undefined ? 'No-Name' : event.name);
context.done(null, {"Hello":name}); // SUCCESS with message
};
```

But I don't know how to use jQuery ajax method to pass "name" parameter to that code. It works when I use:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\": \"PeterChan\"}" https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/test/mydemoresource
```

and I can get the result:

```
{"Hello":"User"}
```

but how can I use jQuery ajax method to pass the "name" variable?

The ajax code that I wrote:

```
var data = {"name":"bbbb"};

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url:"https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/test/mydemoresource",
      data: data,
      //processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
            var text=JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(text);
            //console.log(data);

      },error: function(data) {
            alert("err");
      }
});
```

It alerts an error when I run it.

Comment: Yes Suchit, this is just an example link, in real case I am using my own api url. Thx

Comment: you need to make sure that your url does not gives any server related error.

Comment: You should avoid using "name" as a variable name as it's a javascript keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks like you might have a couple of issues. One, avoid using "name" as a variable name. Two, the data probably isn't being parsed correctly. You need JSON.Stringify when you send it (yeah, you've already got JSON, but it's finicky):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mylambdafunctionurl/',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //success stuff. data here is the response, not your original data
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //error handling stuff
    }
});
```

I've also added crossDomain:true, and contentType: 'application/json'.

In the lambda function to get the key/value in the passed in JSON you just use event.whateverkey (when using the test event in the Lambda console make the keys match what you're sending in to avoid any problems).

The data in your success callback in your ajax function is what comes back from the lambda function, so I recommend JSON.stringifying that in the lambda function, and not the success to make sure it gets sent correctly:

```
context.done(null, JSON.stringify({"Hello":name}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Katharine Osborne~ It works after I add "JSON.stringify(data)" to my code~ One more thing, I would like to ask how can I do it with GET method...for example, I want to access "https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/test/mydemoresource?name=peter" in browser to get the result. I don't know how to config API gateway to do GET method...Thank you and sorry for my poor english~

Comment: I can't show code in a comment, but you would need to make a separate lambda function that uses GET. Your ajax call doesn't need to pass in any data (so you don't need contentType, data, or dataType, and the type is 'GET'. Maybe ask another question and link to it here.